# ArgumentIndexOutOfBounds Exception string.Length

Tags: c#, loops, file-io, exception

Below is a problem that I have been having the past couple of days. This question is very similar to one I asked yesterday, but when I updated the question no one touched it so I am asking it again in a new question.

I am working on a program that takes a large text file, splits it into 2 groups: a and b, and then reads each line of the data. A line of data will look like this:

```
5/22/2015 12:15:55 AM | Batch 8|429/529|81.10 %|BLV-R|Processed VLZYYL...Checking refundable fares. Traditional Booking. Inside ticketing window. Minimum Savings Required: $100.00. Actual Savings: $1,780.60. Savings found: $1,780.60 (31.11 %). Remark written. UDID written. Queued to 0TA9/208*11. Queued to 0TA9/161*222.
```

I am not going to explain what everything means. But the key elements that this program is looking at is "Savings found:" and the percent that is next to it. Not every line however has savings, actually most of the lines do not, but some of them do. Below I have a piece of code that will Tell me what the file name is, how many lines the file has, and look at every line in the a group and write out how many PNRS were processed, how many PNRS have savings, what the percent of all the PNRS that had savings(Percent rounded to 3 decimals) and then it is supposed to write out every line that has "Savings found:" if the percent is  30% or greater, it will place an asterisk infront of the line. If it has 30% or greater savings and has $500 or more in savings, then it will place two asterisks in the front of that line. Below I have an example of what the overall output should be and the code that I have thus far:

```
Console Idea:
FIle Name: PNRS
Total Lines: 123,123

Group: A
Total PNRS: 123
PNRS With Savings: 23
% With Savings: 10%

* 5/21/2015 11:55:56 PM | Batch 6|386/767|50.33 %|CH2M-R|Processed          NXRMN5...Checking refundable and non-refundable fares. Traditional Booking. Inside ticketing window. Minimum Savings Required: $131.00. Actual Savings: $257.18. Savings found: $257.18 (11.55 %). Savings were previously found.
2015-234wefsaf LINE GOES HERE** 2015    LINES 
Group: B SAME FORMAT AS GROUP A
```

Code that I have been working on:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
namespace DanProject
{
class Program_Origional
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //the following series of code is phase1
            try
        {


            string path = @"c:\users\povermyer\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DanProject\PNRS\PNRS.log";

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {

                //Console.WriteLine("File Not Found");
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }
            else
            {


                string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
                var count = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
                List<string> a = lines.Take(7678).ToList();
                List<string> s = lines.Skip(7678).Take(5292).ToList();


                Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path));
                Console.WriteLine(lines.Count());


                if (a.Any(item => item.Contains("Savings found")))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nGroup a\n");
                    var aPNRSThatWereProcessed = a.Count(line => line.Contains("Processed"));

                    Console.WriteLine("There were " + aPNRSThatWereProcessed + " PNRS that were processed in a");


                    //code to find number of savings

                    int aPNRSWhereSavingsWereFound = a.Count(line => line.Contains("Savings found:"));
                    Console.WriteLine("In a, there were " + aPNRSWhereSavingsWereFound + " PNRS that had savings");

                    //code to find percentage for a
                    decimal aPercentage = ((decimal)aPNRSWhereSavingsWereFound / aPNRSThatWereProcessed *100);
                    decimal result1 = Math.Round(aPercentage, 3);
                    Console.WriteLine("The percentage of PNRS in a that had savings were " + result1 + "%");

                    string find = "Savings found:";
                    foreach (var line in a.Where(w => w.Contains(find)))
                    {
                        var subStr = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(find) + find.Length);
                        var startIndex = subStr.IndexOf('(');
                        var endIndex = subStr.IndexOf(')');

                        var savings = double.Parse(subStr.Substring(2, startIndex - 1).Trim());
                        var percent = double.Parse(subStr.Substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex - startIndex - 2).Trim());

                        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", (percent >= 30) ? "*" : string.Empty,

                                                       (percent >= 30 && savings >= 500) ? "*" : string.Empty,
                                                        line);
                    }
                }








            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


    }
}

}
```

My problem lies within the the foreach loop. Everything above that foreach loop is working perfect, and then when I compile this, I am getting this exact error message:
    System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.     Parameter name: length
    at System.String.Substring(Int32, startIndex, Int32, length)
    at (Really long file name for the text file I am working with): line 66

As I can see, the problem is with the .Length statement, however when I try to fix it with the (), VS yells at me and says that I can't do it. It says "Non-invocable member 'string.Length' cannot be used like a method".

Now that I have been as specific, as detailed as possible, please help me in figuring out how I can get rid of this problem and get this console application rolling!

Comment: So which is line 66. Anyway At a guess startIndex, or endIndex aren't what you think, e.g. no ( or ) in a. Debug it.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson line 66, which I apologize btw for not putting that in the question, is (var savings = double.Parse(subStr.Substring(2, startIndex -1).Trim());) that is the line where the problem is. The debugger is skipping everything after that point and moves to the catch block and gives "Length cannot be less than zero.Parameter name: length"

Comment: `var subStr = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(find) + find.Length);` is selecting everything from the start (position zero) of the line up to the end of "Savings found:", but you're looking for the percent value in brackets which appears to be after "Savings found:".

Comment: The argument exception is whinging about startIndex -1 being less than 0 then. Put a conditional debug on it, run your code. see what's in the variables. Going to be a doh moment....

Comment: @steve16351 so how would I change it? Would I change the zero to a one to say it needs to look after the phrase Savings found? Or do you have a different solution?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson conditional debug?

Comment: Stick the red dot n the line. Right Click on it you can add a condition when it will fire e.g. startIndex <= 0. Saves you stepping mullions of times.

Comment: OK so it is stopping at Savings found, which is not whats supposed to be happening, which is obviously what the problem is haha.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson so my next question is, now that I know what the problem is, how do I get it to do what I want? Like how do I get it to read the rest of that phrase? Sorry to ask a lot, I am fairly new to exception handling and parsing

Comment: I can't tell from here. when this happens what does line contain?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson this is the value of line:

5/21/2015 11:55:56 PM | Batch 6|386/767|50.33 %|CH2M-R|Processed NXRMN5...Checking refundable and non-refundable fares. Traditional Booking. Inside ticketing window. Minimum Savings Required: $131.00. Actual Savings: $257.18. Savings found: $257.18 (11.55 %). Savings were previously found.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson this is the value of subStr, where I see the problem:

5/21/2015 11:55:56 PM | Batch 6|386/767|50.33 %|CH2M-R|Processed NXRMN5...Checking refundable and non-refundable fares. Traditional Booking. Inside ticketing window. Minimum Savings Required: $131.00. Actual Savings: $257.18. Savings found:

Answer (score 0):

Then @steve16351 told you what the problem was.

You are doing `var subStr = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(find) + find.Length);`

which will return 'Savings found'

you want something like

```
var subStr = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(find) + find.Length);
```

Which will give you everything after 'Savings found'

Told you it would be a Doh moment. :)

Comment: Not out of the woods yet. :( I am still getting an error. When I run this I get System.FormatExcpetion: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: So check what the substring you are trying to parse is. Has it got the backets or the % in it, say.

Comment: Got to learn to debug mate, sometimes I have to sleep and stuff.

Comment: the substring where the var savings element is gives $257.18 (11.55 %). Savings were previously found. As a value. Then it will go right to the catch block for the error

Comment: Thats why I am very appreciative of all of your hardwork, because I do not know how to debug and I am learning with every comment and the answer as we are going along bud

Comment: No. What does subStr.Substring(2, startIndex - 1) Or the other one evaluate to. If the above isn't 257.18, Parse is going shout and scream or come up with the wrong number. Have a fag and a brew, come back to it.

Comment: So like I said before, it is giving me this: "$257.18 (11.55 %). Savings were previously found." So what you are telling is that all of that extra stuff is what is throwing off everything and it needs to go away, so how do I get it to just read the 257.18

Comment: if substr is  "$257.18 (11.55 %). Savings were previously found." There's no way substr.Substring(2, StartIndex -1) is giving you the same result....